# use qsort with comparator function

Tags: c++, qsort

i know qsort from c library and i have implemented it  with  chars and integers(convert from const void  * form to  relevant form)  but  now i am implementing code which  gives me longest duplicated in given sentences here is simple compare function

```
int pstrcmp(char **p,char **q){
    return strcmp(*p,*q);

}
```

and i want to use it in qsort  like this

```
qsort(a,n,sizeof(char *),pstrcmp);(a is array of strings)
```

when i write directly,it writes it is incompatible and son on,shows me error,please help me  to  correct it

error is this

> 2 IntelliSense: argument of type "int (*)(char **p, char **q)" is 
>   incompatible with parameter of type "int (__cdecl *)(const void *,
>   const void *)"    c:\users\datuashvili\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\duplicate_strings\duplicate_strings\duplicates_strings.cpp  32  27  duplicate_strings

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `qsort` instead of `std::sort` in C++?

Comment: It is much simpler to use `std::sort` from `<algorithm>` with the function `bool pstrcmp(const char* a, const char* b) { return strcmp(a,b) < 0;}`. It is even simpler to use `std::string` where you don't have to implement the comparison function at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give your comparator function the correct function signature and then cast internally, e.g.

```
int pstrcmp(const void * p, const void * q)
{
    const char **ps = (const char **)p;
    const char **qs = (const char **)q;

    return strcmp(*ps, *qs);
}
```